# xCode 14.0.1 - A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, xcode14

I updated my xCode to 14.0.1, after this i am trying to debug the application in iPhone by enable **Automatically manage signing**. But getting the following error as an alert while installing the application in device.

```
A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620395
```

I tried lot of solutions, like

1. Created a new certificate and provisioning profile and tried manual signing
2. Unlocked the device and tried to install the application.
3. Deleted the provisioning profile from device, under Devices and simulator menu.
4. Unpair the device and added the provisioning profile.

But nothing worked, I don't know what is the proper solution to fix this. Anyone please help on this issue.